# using timer to send emails every minute

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm trying to use a timer to send an email every minute. The information for each email is taken from values for each row of components I have on a form. I can send the emails without using the timer, so I know the email method works. But when I try to implement the timer, the emails do not get sent. I read the docs on the timer class, and I believe this should work. But I'm not familiar with it enough to really know what to do. Here is the code:

Here is the email method:

```
//method to send email to outlook
public void sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(string recipient, 
    string subject, string body)
{        
    try
    {    
        // Create the Outlook application.
        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        // Create a new mail item.
        Outlook.MailItem oMsg = 
            (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        // Set HTMLBody. 
        //add the body of the email
        oMsg.Body = body;

        oMsg.Subject = subject;
        // Add a recipient.
        Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
        // Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
        Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(recipient);
        oRecip.Resolve();
        // Send.
        oMsg.Send();
        // Clean up.
        oRecip = null;
        oRecips = null;
        oMsg = null;
        oApp = null;
    }//end of try block
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    } //end of catch
} //end of Email Method
```

And here is the timer event:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (rowClass row in this.rows)
    {
        string recipientAddress = "roomcheckstest@gmail.com";
        string subjectLine = "GPC " + (string)row.buildingComboBox.SelectedItem
            + " " + (string)row.roomComboBox.SelectedItem + "-Room Check";
        string senderline = "Sender=ctsstaff.ithelpcentral@ttu.edu" + "\t";
        string newlinespaces = Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        string legalLastName = "Legal Last Name=" + 
            (string)row.buildingComboBox.SelectedItem;
        string legalFirstName = "Legal First Name=" + 
            (string)row.roomComboBox.SelectedItem;
        string timeLine = "Time= 15m";
        string requestType = "Initial Request Type=Onsite";
        string classRoomMaintenace = "Classroom maintenance. " +
            "Regular Classroom weekly check.";
        string closingEmailSent = "Closing Email Sent=yes";
        string currentlyClosed = "Currently Closed=yes";
        string assignTo = "Assign To=ITHC CTS Staff";
        string typeLine = "Type=Hardware";
        string category = "Category=Internal Component";
        string subCategory = "Subcategory=Performance";
        string agentType = "Type (Agent)=Hardware";
        string agentCategory = "Type (Agent)=Hardware";
        string subCategoryAgent = "Subcategory (Agent)=Performance";
        string labelLine = "Label=Service Request";
        string status = "Status=Closed";
        string finalbody = senderline + newlinespaces + legalLastName 
            + newlinespaces + legalFirstName + newlinespaces + timeLine 
            + newlinespaces + requestType + newlinespaces + classRoomMaintenace 
            + newlinespaces + closingEmailSent + newlinespaces 
            + currentlyClosed + newlinespaces + assignTo + newlinespaces 
            + typeLine + newlinespaces + category + newlinespaces 
            + subCategory + newlinespaces + agentType + newlinespaces 
            + agentCategory + newlinespaces + subCategoryAgent 
            + newlinespaces + labelLine + newlinespaces + status;
        sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(recipientAddress, subjectLine, finalbody);
        MessageBox.Show("email");
        //Thread.Sleep(60000);
        //sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(recipientAddress, subjectLine, finalbody);
    }       
}
```

Here is where the timer is created inside a send email button on the form, which should in theory call the email method:

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rows[0].buildingComboBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer time = new System.Timers.Timer();
        time.Interval = 300000;
        time.Enabled = true;
        time.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        MessageBox.Show("Issues Sent");
    }
}
```

I send an email for each row of components on the form (the user adds rows as needed)
The email is sent through outlook (it has to be sent through outlook using exchange server)
I need to delay it because the server will not accept them all at once. My understanding of the timer class must be flawed. I cant figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but have you verified that the timer is actually running and if it is, that your *this.rows* actually has data?

Comment: yeah. sorry forgot to mention that whenever the user creates a row, it adds it to a rows array, i loop through each member of the array and grab the data from each one and send an email for row in the array

Comment: This isn't directly related to the question, but a code cleanup note: 1.) Your comments are pretty useless. Commenting exactly what the code is doing (i.e. Create new mail item, etc) is not helpful, it just introduces clutter. Comments should be reserved for explaining logic. 2.) Use a `StringBuilder` instead of appending a whole bunch of strings together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to call `.Start()` on the `Timer`.

Note that nothing will happen until the timer ticks, so the first e-mail won't go out immediately.

Also, your timer interval is set to 5 minutes (300,000ms) instead of 1 (60,000ms).

Comment: k. called start() on it. strange. the msdn example didnt call start(). or perhaps i passed over it.

Comment: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'buildingComboBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. hmm

Comment: @Stonep123 Is that happening in the button click handler or in the timer elapsed handler?

Comment: @Stonep123 This is WinForms, right? Try to put all the logic of the handler in another method and invoke it with `this.Invoke` in the timer elapsed handler.

Comment: so say i moved the logic to a sendEmails method..would i call this.Invoke(sendEmails) in the timer handler? its giving me an error when i try and do that. not a delegate method

Comment: @Stonep123 `this.Invoke((Action)sendEmails);`

Comment: hmm..well they sent but now its sending way to many emails...not good

Comment: @Stonep123 It looks like you are sending a message for every row every time the timer elapses (which it will continue to do until you stop it). Also, if your button can be clicked more than once, you'll have a timer for each click, and each of those timers will send a message for each row each time the timer elapses.

Comment: yeah that is definetly what happens...how to fix this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17475/discussion-between-stonep123-and-jay)

Comment: finally got it! worked around the logic and ended up looping through sending emails in the timer event instead of the actual email event. works perfect. thanks a lot for your input

Comment: @Stonep123 Did you see my recommendation in chat?

Comment: i did not, however i finally did get it working late last night. wouldnt have gotten it without your help, thanks man.

Answer (score -3):

You should really use threads when trying to do things like this. Make a class and have it implement Runnable. Then in the implemented function run, make a while loop and then at the end add Thread.sleep(60000).

Comment: Absolutely not. A `Timer` is much more appropriate than locking up a thread.

Comment: yeah i started out using threads...couldnt get it to work. created a new thread...used lambda to call the email function...would never every send mail. I just need to delay the mail while keeping the gui interactive. IT IS SO DIFFICULT

Comment: getting an error with getting the data from  my controls Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'buildingComboBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.